# How to create table with merged cells in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[image]
how too create datatabel in flutter that look like that:

I create  one datatable in  that table data pass by API and I need to show the  data in table forment
in this tabel first two and last two column cell merge size base on middle column data.

```
 DataTable(
      columns: const [
        DataColumn(label: Text("Zone")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Point")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Designation")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Buckle Number")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Police Name")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("District")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Police Station Name")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Age")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Gender")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Number")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Accessories")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Remarks"))
      ],
      rows: controller.eventAssignmentModel.value?.pointAssignments![index]
              .assignedPoliceList!
              .asMap()
              .map((index4, police) => MapEntry(
                  index4,
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(Text(controller.eventAssignmentModel.value!.pointAssignments![index].zoneName!)),
                    DataCell(Text(controller.eventAssignmentModel.value!.pointAssignments![index].pointName!)),
                    DataCell(Text(police.designation ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.buckleNumber ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.policeName ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.district ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.policeStationName ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.age ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.gender ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(police.number ?? '')),
                    DataCell(Text(controller.eventAssignmentModel.value!.pointAssignments![index].pointAccessories!)),
                    DataCell(Text(controller.eventAssignmentModel.value!.pointAssignments![index].pointRemarks!)),
                  ])))
              .values
              .toList() ??
          const [],
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about in in the opposite way: not merging, but rather splitting cells.

Since `TableRow` accepts any widget in children, you can put a table inside a table, achieving basically the same result. Please check the following code, you can run it in Dartpad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: [
            const TableRow(children: [
              Text('Column 1'),
              Text('Column 2'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              const Text('Entry 1'),
              Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: const [
                TableRow(children: [
                  Text('Nested Entry 1'),
                  Text('Nested Entry 2'),
                ]),
                TableRow(children: [
                  Text('Nested Entry 3'),
                  Text('Nested Entry 4'),
                ]),
              ]),
            ]),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I try  this  but  when I integrate  API  for  data  that table  does not work

Comment: that's a problem with your api data or how you are trying to fill the table with it. most likely inconsistent number of cells in rows. you may share details if you'd like to. as far as the ui solution provided in my answer, you can test it in Dartpad. it does what is required.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter doesn’t have rowspan and colspan capabilities as far as i know...
You can try this=> https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-table-but-columns-are-mergable/